# Opacity/Brightness with Mouseover on an imagemap

Tags: html, css, opacity, imagemap, brightness

I have a picture with many people (~30) and I want to change the Opacity of specific areas when my mouse is above a face.
Id like to make that with Gimp (if possible?) and an imagemap.

What exactly I want:

I want to move my mouse over a face and the area AROUND the face (in a shape), im over, should be totally bright, which means the opacity should be changed. So the face in the middle is normal, and a small part around the face is brighter (or white).

I cant find anything in the internet, I just got some ideas but no clear idea how I should do it. 
Probably with an opacity map? With slices? With div's?

Would be great if someone could help me or even have a code example!

Comment: It is a little complicated but not imposible, what have you tried? share on codepen.

Comment: I currently have 'just' the imagemaps with the areas around the face. I tried some things with for example mouseover, but I didnt know/dont know how to change the brightness just for one specific area, and not the whole picture. So for example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZRagm

Comment: Your codepen example is not working, use `src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/" ` to load images in image tag

Comment: [I hope that works](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZRagm)

Comment: I think I dont have much yet, I tried to use the code from the duplicate (Pauli_D etc.) but.. I simply dont know how to make what I want at all.. Everything I tried didn't go well and I can't start now without even having a clue how

Comment: this image `src="./images/Klassenfoto.jpg"` will not load for me, it only will be visible in your computer, try to use another image loaded in some server, example `src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/" ` also ask a new question because it is marked as duplicated. I am sure i can help.

Comment: Thanks! Done.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556268/how-to-change-the-brightness-on-the-edge-of-an-area-in-an-imagemap-with-mouseove